# Swipe overlay off screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, touch

I have created a simple webpage for a touch screen info kiosk. The homepage has a full screen overlay that, when touched, slides off the screen (using *animate.css*).

I would now like some additional functionality (to improve usability). Would it be possible for users to **swipe** the overlay off the screen, instead of touching it and having it 'slide away'. I've noticed that some users instinctively swipe left/right when they approach the screen for the first time. When this doesn't work half of them walk away assuming it's broken, not thinking to touch the screen with one finger.

- If the user swipes left the overlay should slide off the screen to the left.
- If the user swipes right the overlay should slide off the screen to the right.
- If the user swipes up the overlay should slide off the screen to the top.
- etc

I had been looking at [this jQuery plugin](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/index.html) - would this work?

I have no idea how I would incorporate such a feature. I have however [created a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/johnny_s/axb97xwk/2/) of my work so far (stripped down for example purposes). Also included all of my code (duplication of the jsfiddle).

### Any help or guidance is appreciated.

HTML

```
<body>
  <!-- start overlay -->
  <div class="overlay overlay-data">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 overlay-info">
          <p class="help-heading">Help?</p>
          <div class="circle"></div>
          <div class="pulse-ring"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end ovberlay-->
  <div class="container text-center">
    <!-- first row -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="menu-item blue" id="loader1">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-signs big-icon"></i>
                    <p>Guides</p></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="menu-item blue" id="loader4">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart big-icon"></i>
                    <p>Borrowing</p></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="menu-item blue" id="loader7">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-binoculars big-icon"></i>
                    <p>Finding books</p></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end first row -->
  </div>
  <!-- Start Main Body Section -->
  <div class="mainbody-section text-center">
    <div class="partners">
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="navModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <hr>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="navModalLabel">
                        Navigation</h4><img src="images/bs_touchscreen_nav.jpg">
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end main body -->
  </div>
</body>
```

---

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".overlay").addClass('overlay-open');
  $("section, .container").addClass('blur');
});

$(document).on('click', '.overlay', function() {
  $('.overlay').addClass('animated slideOutUp');
  $("section, .container").removeClass('blur');
});
```

---

CSS

```
body {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%
}

.btn-primary {
  border-color: #FF432E;
  background-color: #FF432E;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -o-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.blue {
  background: #28ABE3;
}

.menu-item {
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
}

.menu-item:hover {
  border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.70);
}

.menu-item a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.menu-item a p {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.menu-item a i {
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.menu-item:hover a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 1;
}

.overlay p {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  height: 30%;
  font-size: 120px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

.overlay-data {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  visibility: 0s 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0s 0.5s;
}

.overlay-open {
  opacity: 0.5;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.overlay-info {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.circle {
  padding: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.pulse-ring {
  //content: '';
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: -110px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  animation: pulsate infinite 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ann0nC0d3r this worked. If you can add an answer I'll gladly accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into to using jQuery Mobile UI: [api.jquerymobile.com/swipe](http://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe) which supports swipe events.

You can then just add whatever animate.css classes you need depending on the action :)